# Can I use Metamask with promise async calls instead of nested callbacks?

Tags: dapp-development, metamask

I'm trying to use promises instead of nested callbacks for better readabilty. 
When I use this code:

```
balanceUpdate: function() {

    MyWallet.deployed().then(function(instance) {
     return web3.eth.getBalance(instance.address);
    }).then(function(walletBalance) {
      document.getElementById("walletEther").innerHTML = web3.fromWei(walletBalance).toNumber();
      return web3.eth.getBalance(account);
    }).then(function(accountBalance) {
      document.getElementById("accountEther").innerHTML = web3.fromWei(accountBalance).toNumber();
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.error(error);
      throw "Can't get balances"
    })   
}
```

I got this error when Metamask is active:

```
Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_getBalance without a callback parameter. See https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async---think-of-metamask-as-a-light-client for details.
```

It works fine if I use a nested callback but I find it much less readable:

```
balanceUpdate: function() {

    MyWallet.deployed().then(function(instance) {

      web3.eth.getBalance(instance.address, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
        } else {
          document.getElementById("walletEther").innerHTML = web3.fromWei(result.toNumber());
          web3.eth.getBalance(account, function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
              console.error(error);
            } else {
              document.getElementById("accountEther").innerHTML = web3.fromWei(result.toNumber());
            }
          }); // getbalance account
        }
      }); // getBalance instance.address
    }); // MyWallet.deployed
  }, // balanceUpdate
```

I've found [this issue ("Promisify TxManager")](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-plugin/issues/957) on Metamask's github. Not sure if it's related.

Any suggestion how to avoid nested callbacks and be able to use Metamask the same time?

Even the [samples on truffle sites](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract#full-example) are using promises. Is it possible that those samples won't work with Metamask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The web3 object that is currently injected by MetaMask and other web3 browsers does not return promises.

The MetaMask issue you linked is not related to this.

Truffle has its own Contract library that returns promises, this works with MetaMask and other web3 browsers, that's why it returns promises but the pure web3 doesn't.

The `web3` object itself is even [going to be deprecated from Mist](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/v0.8.10) [and MetaMask](https://twitter.com/metamask_io/status/862074263574110208) in the not-too distant future. That's one of the reasons that most of the [web3 code samples](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check) you'll find show you to check for web3, and then recommend initializing your own web3 object with its `web3.currentProvider` object.

In the future, this `provider` will be the important, low-level piece that you use to initialize other libraries that meet your programming style.

A new cool library you might enjoy that works with MetaMask, uses its provider, but returns promises is [ethjs](https://github.com/ethjs), I recommend you check it out!